# I would like to know the cause of the "No Property Database found under this URN"

Tags: autodesk-forge

When I load an IFC file into a reb drawing in Rebro, convert it to an ifc file, and try to import it using the Forge API, it fails and logs "diagnostic
No Property Database found under this URN" log.
I could not find a solution to this in other questions on stack overflow, so I would like to know if you have any reference information to help me solve this problem.

Here is the API I used

```
POST /modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
```

Expected Result

Success in translating.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically an issue with the specific IFC file containing some unusual/unexpected data. If you'd be willing to share the design with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (confidentially - we would not share the design with anyone outside of the company), we'd be happy to have the Model Derivative service team debug the translation on their end.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I have again examined the ifc-file used for the translation on my end, and I suspect that the values used in the following functions may be the cause of the failure.
"FCFLOWTERMINAL"
"IFCLIGHTFIXTURETYPE"
"IFCPROPERTYLISTVALUE"
"IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE"

I have just sent the subject file with the error to "forge.help@autodesk.com". I have attached the stack overflow page link here in the email. I would appreciate it if you could share your debugging details.

Thank you.